# Can I replace more than one value in a column using just one line code in power query?

Tags: powerquery

I need to replace different texts with the same output and a don't want to do it one by one.

One example in the cells is:
Manutenção;Meta 5;Detalhamento Gov. Ferramentas
[image]

I tried this, but it didn't work.
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado",{"Detalhamento Gov.Ferramentas", "Manutenção"},"",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Rótulos"})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Replace={"Moose","Okapi"},
Alternate="Something",
#"Replace2" = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Column1", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(Text.Split(_,";"),each if List.Contains(Replace,_) then Alternate else _),";"), type text}})
in  #"Replace2"
```

[image]

**EDIT** you want the code that is described as slow, but for your case the best way, from https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/05/22/multiple-replacements-in-power-bi-and-power-query/

```
let Replacements = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Replacements"]}[Content],
TextToChange = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Text"]}[Content],
WordsToReplace = List.Buffer(Replacements[Word To Replace]),
WordsToReplaceWith = List.Buffer(Replacements[Replace With]),
ReplacementFunction = (InputText)=> 
 let DoReplacement = List.Generate(
                      ()=> [Counter=0, MyText=InputText], 
                      each [Counter]<=List.Count(WordsToReplaceWith), 
                      each [Counter=[Counter]+1, 
                            MyText=Text.Replace(
                                     [MyText], 
                                     WordsToReplace{[Counter]}, 
                                     WordsToReplaceWith{[Counter]})], 
                      each [MyText]),
   GetLastValue = List.Last(DoReplacement)
 in
  GetLastValue,
Output = Table.AddColumn(TextToChange, "Changed Text List.Generate", each ReplacementFunction([Text])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Output,{"Text"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @horseyride. I'm gonna try it and then I post again.

Comment: How'd that work out for you

Comment: It has worked for some strings, but the "Meta " asnd ";" string hasn't. I just want to keep the number.

Comment: edited above with diff code